# Handling dynamic parameter value while creating a stack in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Can someone help me out in handling a dynamic "ParameterValue" in parameter.json file.

I'm running "cloudformation create-stack" and passing in --parameters a parameter.json file, there are few "ParameterValue" in the file that needs to be dynamic for example, timestamp and appending index values from loop etc... so, how can i modify the parameters.json file to handle dynamic values.

Alternate way i could go with is to just not use the parameters.json file and pass in the key, value like below to the create-stack command inside the loop in the script,

--parameters ParameterKey="XYZ",ParameterValue="${someval}${index}"

Comment: At what point in the process do you need to evaluate the dynamic values in your parameters?

Comment: before the create-stack operation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create `parameters.json.template` file to hold the values in their parameterized form like you show:

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "XYZ",
        "ParameterValue": "{someval}{index}"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "ABC",
        "ParameterValue": "staticval-{suffix}"
    }
]
```

I am assuming you are doing this on the cli, based on the use of the `--parameters` flag.  In that case, I would create a script to merge the template file with the values (into a generated file) and call the create-stack cli command after that.

Something like this on linux:

```
#! /bin/bash

# create output file from template
cp templates/parameters.json.template generated/parameters.json

# merge dynamic values into templated file
sed -i "s/{someval}/$SOME_VAL/g" generated/parameters.json
sed -i "s/{index}/$INDEX/g" generated/parameters.json
sed -i "s/{suffix}/$SUFFIX/g" generated/parameters.json

aws cloudformation create-stack ... --parameters generated/parameters.json ...
```

This of course assumes your script has access to your dynamic values.